# Dataproc gcloud default_config permission denied error

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

Our project is using dataproc, and I have checked for service account that is indicated in master and worker compute engines that it has required permissions for my bucket storage. Nevertheless, in log viewer I have seen following:

> (gsutil) Failed to create the default configuration. Ensure your have the correct permissions on: [/home/.config/gcloud/configurations]. Could not create directory [/home/.config/gcloud/configurations]: Permission denied. Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent directory.

What can I do to fix this issue? I should download some file from this bucket and using gsutil to do that.

PS: I have tried using action.sh to find out logged in user which results in nothing.

PS2: We are using SparkSession for this operation.

Comment: Please share whole error message.

Comment: The gsutil permission error is not about IAM permission but Linux user permission. Can you SSH into the VM and check if you have permission to create the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening support ticket to google cloud, it is indicated that this was an error of Unix permissions, and they suggested me to use gcs-connector which is working.

Answer (score 0):

The gsutil permission error is not about IAM permission but Linux user permission. Can you SSH into the VM and check if you have permission to create the folder? You can also run `gsutil ...` to test the command.

Comment: One part of the project uses gsutil to download csv and use it using spark. I have copied that part, and created a new project, lets call it B. For B, there is no problem with gsutil, but for the main project, I have kept getting same error. Both uses the same cluster.

Comment: So you mean you are using gsutil in a spark job? Is the call to gsutil running in driver or executors?

Comment: Yes, we are using gsutil in a spark job. I couldn't understand the part driver and executors. Do you mean master and workers ?

Comment: Some spark code runs in spark driver, e.g., init spark session and other init; some code runs in spark executors, e.g. reading and writing data, transformation.

Comment: This is a key information, you need to update the question with it.

Comment: we are using spark sessions. Both of the projects I talked about earlier uses spark sessions.

Comment: In Spark we usually use GCS connector to access GCS, it is available by default.